# pythonの出力に関する質問です。

Tags: python

pythonに関する質問です。

多値分類（今回は3クラス）において複数の分類器のアンサンブルをしようと思います。
各分類器の出力に誤り率に基づく重みを掛け合わせたものを足し合わせたいと考えています。（イメージ的にはAdaBoost）

DTを決定木　その重みをa1、SVMをSVM分類器　その重みをa2としたときに

---

```
DT=[0]*3  #[0,0,0]
SVM=[0]*3  #[0,0,0]

for i in range(0,len(x_test)):
    DT[DT.predict(x_test(i))] = a1  #DTの推定したクラスにa1を代入
    SVM [SVM.predict(x_test(i))] = a2  #SVMの推定したクラスにa2を代入
```

---

上記のfor文の＃のような操作ができませんアドバイスお願いします。
また、コードが汚くてすみません。

Comment: 疑似ソースでは意味がないですよ。
決定木とSVMの分類器が出してくる結果の値がどういうものなのか、正確に示した方がいいと思います。
DTとSVMの名前のかぶりも気になります。

Comment: タグでpythonの質問と分かります。タイトルには質問の要約を書いてください。